# Calabash by Xamarin Not Found on Component Store in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, calabash-ios

Have you removed  this components from Components storein Xamarin Studio ? If yes then how to force load calabash framework in xamarin ios project. If any alternative option is available in place of calabash by Xamarin for iOS only(Except UI.Test Xamarin framework) in Components, then let me know.  Looking forward to response from your side.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [TestCloudAgent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent/) from Nuget.